# Can't run Docker container from image after commit

Tags: ubuntu, docker, xrdp

I use Docker image from [github](https://github.com/hiroom2/doxrdp) to have a Ubuntu with xrdp, but when I make some changes (for example create new folder), exit the container, commit changes and create new image, I can't start container from this new image.
I'm getting this kind of message:

```
 * Starting enhanced syslogd rsyslogd
   ...done.
 * Removing stale PID file /var/run/dbus/pid.
 * Starting system message bus dbus

 Failed to start message bus: Failed to bind socket "/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket": Address already in use
```

I start docker container with:

```
docker run b3bdcd8a8a9d -p 3391:3389 2f60daa82fce
```

then connect with RDP, make some changes, disconect, stopping container and commiting changes with

```
docker commit 7d372287aa09 test
```

I use Ubuntu 14.04.2.

What could be the cause of such behavior?

Comment: That error message suggests that there is another program using the port `3391`. Are you using `docker stop` to stop the container?

Comment: it would help you to view what ports are busy ... what is your host OS ?  the one where you launch your docker commands  ?  if its linux then issue this to display what processes are using what ports ... sudo netstat -peanut

Comment: stop the containers and start again

Comment: The port `3391` is not used, there is no problem with running new container from the orginal image. I used `docker stop` and also try `docker pause`. Host OS is Ubuntu 14.04.02.

Comment: I have the same problem